# Is there a way to link fb:comments to a page rather than an App

Tags: plugins, facebook, fbml

I am trying to implement the fb:comments plugin on a microsite, and link it to a fan page that I have already set up.

Due to the fact that my organization already has many followers on our Facebook Page, I don't want to direct anyone to the application page if at all possible. Instead I want everyone to be directed to our FB page.

I am talking specifically about when a user posts a comment using FB comments and it shows up in their feed and their friends feed as:

time posted via app_name.

When the user clicks on the App_Name it goes to the App (makes sense) but I'd like it to go to the Page instead.

The reason I am asking if this is possible is because the plugin fb:live-stream has a via_url: parameter that will allow a user to navigate to the Site URL set up in the application (Directed to a facebook page).

I have tried using the `url` parameter with no luck.

Is this possible? Am I on a wild goose chase? Should I just set up the App page and hope for the best? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this. A year after posting this question and more development knowledge under my belt I have definitely learned that is is not possible.

A good way to work around this is to set up the app page to redirect to the facebook fan page when a user lands on it.